# Excel formula: How do I remove last two digits or last two letters in column?

Tags: excel

For example:

[image]

How do I remove the last 2 letters or digits on the next column?

Comment: what you want to say, clear the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Should do it.

`=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)`

What we do in the formula is ask for the Left side of the text from the total string lenght minus two, which removes the 2 last characters in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data starts with A1 and apply the below formula in b1 and drag down (select B1 to B11 and CTRL + D)

```
=RIGHT(A1,2)
```

[image]

Comment: i want to remove the last two digits or letter